# SoapUI mock service always returns log page at root

Tags: mocking, soapui

I am attempting to deploy a mock REST service with SoapUI. I am using SoapUI's 'Deploy As War' facility, with Tomcat as the container, on `localhost:8080` (on WinXP). Any requests I make when running the service return the SoapUI mock service log page, however. So if the root of the service is `http://localhost:8080/foo/`, and I make a request to `http://localhost:8080/foo/bar`, the response will be the HTML of the log page at the root (code is 200).

I believe I have everything set up correctly in my WEB-INF/web.xml, as outlined [here](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=11384):

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>SoapUIMockServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Everything works as expected when running the service from within SoapUI itself.

My context path was set to '/foo'. I have my foo.war and the war directory itself under Tomcat's webapps directory. I have noticed, however, that when I attempt to access the wsdl from the log page all I get is this:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
</wsdl:definitions>
```

No idea if that's what I'm supposed to be seeing, or if that's at all relevant.

New to Tomcat and relatively new to SoapUI. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: For the record this also happens under Jetty and JBoss, so is not specific to Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you tried this guide ["Mocking with a custom OnRequest Script"](http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/mocking-rest-services.html)

As you can [see](https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/blob/master/soapui/src/main/java/com/eviware/soapui/mockaswar/MockAsWarServlet.java#L259), it is a gap.. The Servlet will only recognize the exact path:

```
if( pathInfo.equals( mockRunner.getMockService().getPath() ) )
```

You can rewrite the servlet to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with that piece of documentation. Forgive me, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'a gap', in this context. I tried setting the exact path in the script, and also in WEB-INF/web.xml servlet-mapping section (`<url-pattern>http://localhost:8080/*</url-pattern>`). In the first instance I got the same problem as before, in the latter I got errors when I ran Tomcat, and couldn't even get to http://localhost:8080 in the browser.

Comment: http://www.soapui.org/images/stories/Getting_Started/Generate_MockService_Dialog_soapUI.png

Comment: if you see the image http://www.soapui.org/images/stories/Getting_Started/Generate_MockService_Dialog_soapUI.png the path field is exact mockRunner.getMockService().getPath() varaible. url-pattern will not be affected because the "/*" i.e. the context or resource part of the URL will be ignored because must match exact. To fix this I patched this line to replace equals by startsWith.

Comment: gap is term used in my country to say that a bug is a thing that nobody asked for it. e.g. This product has a gap. See my patch https://github.com/mtheus/soapui/commit/1771c3beb8addbe595f98f418d1f4379206fdb0d

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. My sincere apologies! I will patch this in. Thank you.